# Dynamic theme change on Angular ag-grid with infinite scroll

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an Ag-grid in my Angular 9 application with infinite scroll working properly and I want to implement a theme chooser like the one in the [demo](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php).

However, simply changing the CSS class is not enough to change the theme, because row heights are not being updated upon theme change.

I tried calling `refreshCells` and `resetRowHeights` after changing the theme, but neither updates the row heights.

The source code of the demo seems to destroy and recreate the grid upon theme change, and [this](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/3653) GitHub issue seems to confirm that the best way to change the theme dynamically is to destroy the grid and recreate it.

However, I haven't been able to find a way to recreate the grid after calling `gridApi.destroy()`.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found myself an answer in [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/95RG6dieL8VRqP1l?preview):

To destroy and recreate the grid, it needs to be in a container element with `*ngIf`, so that it can be removed and recreated dynamically: for instance, if the container element is

```
<div *ngIf="gridActive">
    <ag-grid ....>
</div>
```

Then in the component code the theme change can be done by doing:

```
recreateGrid() {
    this.gridActive = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.gridActive = true;
    });
}
```